# Separate elements in a list and print as tags per element

Tags: python, list, tags

How can I think when I want to write code that shows this as output:

```
versions: [ 'version:1.0', 'version:1.1', 'version:1.2' ]

<version>
    <1>
    <0>
<version>
    <1>
    <1>
<version>
    <1>
    <2>
```

I have tried with this code so far, but it won't print the last number and the tags "<>".

```
versions = [ 'version:1.0', 'version:1.1', 'version:1.2' ]

for version in versions:
    print(version.split(':')[0])
    print(version.split(':')[1])
```

Comment: Are you looking to construct a html out of this? Are 1, 0 etc. child tags of 'version' elements?

Comment: No I don't want to construct html, just want to print the text as stated above. Yes the numbers belong to each version elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an f-String to format your Strings as follows:

```
versions = [ 'version:1.0', 'version:1.1', 'version:1.2' ]

for version in versions:
    print(f"<{version.split(':')[0]}>")
    print(f"<{version.split(':')[1]}>")
```

This way you can use code in your print statement.

Regarding the printing of the version numbers as seperate:

```
for version in versions:
    print(f"<{version.split(':')[0]}>")
    print(f"<{(version.split(':')[1]).split('.')[0]}>")
    print(f"<{(version.split(':')[1]).split('.')[1]}>")
```

You can split the result of a split command even further and use different seperators.

This should result in the following output:

```
<version>
<1>
<0>
<version>
<1>
<1>
<version>
<1>
<2>
```

You could add whitespaces to indent the version numbers.